# How to get argument with id in cypress

Tags: jquery, typescript, protractor, automated-tests, cypress

I am converting protractor to cypress page object model below is function and i want to write it in cypress like

## ***Protractor version**

```
this.getConfigButtons = function(module) {
    return element(by.id("test-sidebar-buttons-" + module));*
}
```

## **Cypress version

```
public getConfigButtons(module:any){
   return cy.get('.test-sidebar-buttons-').find(module)**
}
```

but its not  working

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
public getConfigButtons(module:any) {

return cy.get('.test-sidebar-buttons-' + module)
```